# JQuery get td closest to given X,Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simulating a drag and drop for mobile. I had a lot of trouble using ready made libraries to **convert mouse events** to touch events such as `touchPunch.js` and `hammer.js` so I decided to do it myself.

```
    var td;
    var tr;
    var id;
    var xy;
    var element;

        function touchHandler(e) {                 
                if (e.type == 'touchstart') {

                    element = $(e.target).closest('div.sensor');
                    id = $(e.target).closest('div.sensor').attr('id');

                } else if (e.type == 'touchmove') {

                    xy = e.targetTouches[0];
                    $(element).css({ position: 'absolute', top: xy.pageY, left: xy.pageX }).appendTo('body');                       

                } else if (e.type == 'touchend') {

                    xy = e.targetTouches[0];

                    // here I need to get the closest td

                }
            }
```

On `touchstart` I capture the element and the element Id.

On `touchmove` I get the XY coordinates of the mouse and manually move the element to that point. (append it to the body...)

On `touchend` I would like to find the closest td on the page and snap the element back into the grid.

Any ideas on how to get the closest td based on the XY coordinates?

Thank you!

Comment: Something you could try is to store all the coordinates of the elements you want to track beforehand and then iterate through them, something like https://franciscohodge.com/2018/01/14/find-closest-element-click-coordinates-javascript-coding-question/